# Gradle properties are missing for 'GitHubPackages' credentials

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to build my spring boot project in IntelliJ idea but it gives the following error. I am using Gradle to build the project.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.MissingValueException: The following Gradle properties are missing for 'GitHubPackages' credentials:
  - GitHubPackagesUsername
  - GitHubPackagesPassword
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.CredentialsProviderFactory$CredentialsProvider.assertRequiredValuesPresent(CredentialsProviderFactory.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.CredentialsProviderFactory$PasswordCredentialsProvider.call(CredentialsProviderFactory.java:138)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a gradle.properties file that contains the following properties

```
GitHubPackagesUsername=yourUsername
GitHubPackagesPassword=tokenId
```

and save it in the .gradle folder

Comment: but before it was enough to just set `maven {
                name = "GitHubPackages"
                url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/HIDDEN_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW")
                credentials {
                    username = System.getenv("GPR_USER")
                    password = System.getenv("GPR_KEY")
                }
            }`

Comment: For me this was linked with the configuration cache, once I disabled it the issue went away, see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/24329